# Default values in parameter

Tags: c#, parameters

```
public void FooBar(String _connectionString, Decimal p_Query_Type, DateTime? p_Date_Start = new DateTime(2006, 1, 1), DateTime? p_Date_End, Decimal? p_Number = null, Decimal? p_Group_Id = null)
```

Visual Studio doesn't like how I initialized p_Date_Start

how do I set a value if the developer using my API doesn't need a value to p_Date_Start?

Error from Visual Studio

> Error CS1736  Default parameter value for 'p_Date_Start' must be a
>   compile-time constant

Comment: try to declare your 2006, 1, and 1 as a static value

Comment: @Lotan Only consts can be used as default values, so that won't help

Comment: Default the datetime to null, DateTime? p_Date_Start = null, then at the beginning of your method do p_Date_Start ??= new DateTime(2006, 1, 1)

Comment: I would just write two overloads to be honest...

Comment: @canton7 you're right :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Default parameter for value must be a compile time constant.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) Dynamically calculated value is not accepted by compiler against optional parameter.

Let's say as anlternative `DateTime?  = null;` and in method,

```
var effective_p_Date_Start = p_Date_Start ?? new DateTime(2006, 1, 1)
```

If necessary, you can follow up the way for others.

Answer (score 0):

roughly like this:

in methodhead use

```
DateTime? p_Date_Start = null
```

and in the method:

```
p_Date_Start ??= new DateTime(2006, 1, 1)
```

also I should mention that `DateTime? p_Date_End` also needs a default since all optional parameters must come at last

Answer (score 0):

You can use `null` as the default value, and then handle the `null` case in the method body:

```
public void FooBar(String _connectionString, Decimal p_Query_Type, DateTime? p_Date_Start = null, DateTime? p_Date_End, Decimal? p_Number = null, Decimal? p_Group_Id = null)
{
  if (p_Date_Start == null) p_Date_Start = new DateTime(2006, 1, 1);
  // more stuff here
}
```